# Why this code not works ? Nothing happens after running ? I would like to have validation error in my view

Tags: c#, wpf

such code I have in the view

```
<TextBox 
        Text="{Binding MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        Name="MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzinText" Margin="50 50 50 50">
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Placeholder for the TextBox itself -->
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

and such code in the model

```
public string MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin
{
    get { return miejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin; }

    set
    {
        this.miejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin = "aaa";

        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged( string miejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(miejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin));
}
```

I have written digits for example `2222` in my textbox in view and an error doesn't show there.

Comment: Try `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin));`

Comment: Why would you expect an error? MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin is a string, and 2222 is a valid string. You're also setting the backing variable to a fixed string rather than value in the setter so miejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin will always be set to "aaa"

Comment: You are right  Andy, good point of view . Could you show me how to use OnPropertyChanged() with  double variable that  after I will  get validation error in view ?Thanks so much for help .

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox Name="MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzinText" Margin="50 50 50 50">
    <TextBox.Text>
       <Binding Path="MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
             <Binding.ValidationRules>
                  <local:MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzinTextRule />
             </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Placeholder for the TextBox itself -->
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

and

```
public class MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzinTextRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        //example test
        if(value.ToString() == "aaa")
            return new ValidationResult(false, $"Error: value = aaa");
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

don't forget to modify

```
public string MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin
{
    get => miejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin;
    set
    {
        this.miejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin = value;//"aaa";

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MiejsceWykonaniaNadgodzin));
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks but I have got an error in line. could not be assigned value,  expected ValidationRule . I add that my MyCustomConverter implement ValidationRule             `<local:MyCustomConverter /> `

Comment: Can you show me your MyCustomConverter implementation